# Setting cookies via mod_rewrite fails

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, cookies

I'm building a site on top of CodeIgniter. To make URIs look prettier CI uses mod_rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|fonts|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [NC]
```

Now I'd like to allow people to request pages in a specific language, i.e. process both normal https://example.com/home and language-specific https://example.com/spa/home. At this stage it's pretty troubling for me to create new controllers, so I want to set language cookie and rewrite the original URI. After reading some good articles on mod_rewrite, I came up with this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(eng|spa|ger|fre)/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %2 [R,NC,QSA,CO=lang:%1:.example.com:1440:/]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|fonts|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [NC]
```

However, when I try to access https://example.com/spa/home the URI doesn't get rewritten, `lang` cookie not set, and 404 Page Not Found error is returned.

My guess is that my rule and the original CodeIgniter rule are conflicting. Are they? And is it my only mistake?

Many thanks!

UPD: Apache/2.4.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(eng|spa|ger|fre)/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(eng|spa|ger|fre)/(.*)$ /$2 [R,NC,QSA,CO=lang:%1:ubtv.local:1440:/]
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. Probably I should remake the original CI rewrite rule but I can't touch it now because users might not be able to access the site. I think I'm just gonna set up CI on a dev server and try to play around with these two rules. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: What about adding de "L" flag? I did the test with a Drupal installation and it doesn't work without being "last" rule: `RewriteRule ^(eng|spa|ger|fre)/(.*)$ /$2 [R,L,NC,QSA,CO=lang:%1:ubtv.local:1440:/]`. Also check that before the rules you have enabled rewrite with: `RewriteEngine on`. And a good thing would be that you post your full **.htaccess** or ruleset.

Comment: I was 100% sure that adding L flag will invalidate the main CI rewrite rule, so I was preparing to post my .htaccess. But it didn't! I don't know what happened but I know I owe you a great deal :)

Comment: BTW, Apache is supposed to stop rewriting when it meets L flag, but obviously now it doesn't stop on the first rule (the one suggested by you), when the condition is met and continues to the base CI rewrite rule. Why is that?

Comment: Well, if your read this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l , it says "In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed.". So it's not absolutely true that it ends the processing of rules. In fact, what I understand from this documentation is that when the rule causes a redirect, it is possible that all the ruleset is processed again, obviously, in your case, the second time the rules are processed will not match this rule.

Answer (score 1):

`/spa/home` is an uri its not a `querystring` , so you need to match against the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable like the following

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(eng|spa|ger|fre)/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%2 [R,NC,QSA,CO=lang:%1:.example.com:1440:/]
```